# Need help saving php variable from HTML select dropbox

Tags: php, html

I thinks this is pretty easy but yet can't do it for the sake of my life. Is this too much to ask for?

```
 <select name="cars">
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {
$car = $_POST['cars'];
}
?>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</body>  


</head>
<body>
<Form name ="form1" Method ="POST" Action ="">
<Input Type = "text" Value ="<?php echo $car; ?>" Name ="word">
<Input Type = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" Value = "Submit">
</FORM>
```

Comment: Not quite understanding your structure here... Why does `</body>` appear before `<body>`?

Comment: Learn HTML first. Then try to do things like this.

Comment: okay that was just me being not careful. obviously <body> comes before </body>

but srs what are some possible reasons that the variable $car wouldn't get stored?

Comment: The thing is your question is really bad written. You don't even explain what you want. We are supposed to help you with a specific problem, not to guess what you need and then give you a solution. It's not obvious what you want to do here and, as far as I can see, the HTML is wrong. It wasn't my intention to mock at you. I really thought you didn't know how a lot of HTML.

Comment: no its my fault I really should have payed attention

Answer (score 0):

The `<select>` tag is an HTML form element and in order to be submitted that tag would have to be inside the `<form>` tag.

Your new code should look like this:

```
    <body>
    <form name="form1" method="POST" action="">
     <select name="cars">
      <?php
       if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {
        $car = $_POST['cars'];
       }
       ?>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
     </select>
     <input type="text" value="<?php echo $car; ?>" name="word" />
     <input type="Submit" name="Submit1" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    </body>
```

Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Thank you Stephen. Clear, and informative answer. Wish more ppl were like you.